# Round decimal in Angular 4 Component

Tags: angular

I get an error trying to round a decimal to two digits using DecimalPipe inside of a controller.
When I try

```
   import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
    .....

    var networth = (this.decimalPipe.transform(p.usdPrice * portfolioRecord.amount, '1.2-2'));
    //currentWorth field is a "number" type.
    portfolioRecord.currentWorth = networth;
```

the "networth" variable is a "string | null" type and cannot be set to a number.  What is the best way to round a decimal inside the controller so I can set it to a number variable?

Update:   using answer from comments:

```
var networth = p.usdPrice * portfolioRecord.amount;
portfolioRecord.currentWorth = +networth.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: it could be set to a number, try the number constructor

Comment: The number would be `p.usdPrice * portfolioRecord.amount`? You could use `.toFixed(2)` for example

Comment: var networth = p.usdPrice * portfolioRecord.amount;
portfolioRecord.currentWorth = +networth.toFixed(2);

Comment: That worked.  Just had to cast a number using "+".